# Is there an API to export completed Google Checkout orders?

Tags: google-api, google-checkout

I've Googled this a 100 times, and I must be looking in all the wrong places, or looking up the wrong terms.  I just don't know.

Basically, in my Google Checkout inbox, I can see all my customers' orders: Chargeable, Canceled, Charged, etc.  I can export the CSV at the bottom of the page too.

However, is there an API I can use to write a script to export Charged orders between 2 dates?

I see tons of API info for using Google Checkout to make and accept orders, but I can't find anything to pull my merchant data OUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course I find the answer RIGHT AFTER posting this.  So, I would like to share what I found in case someone else has the same question.

Google's Polling API (beta at time of posting this)
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Beta_Polling_API.html

And Notifications:
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html

It appears that Polling allows you to request information and Notifications requires a secure web servers for sending notifications about orders to your server.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a tool available (report.jar) that will allow you to leverage the Polling API to create detailed reports. The article below covers how to use the report.jar tool:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/articles/Order_Report_Tutorial.html